# Design an angularjs proj that has 2 apps using a common component that in turn uses an app specific component that uses code in common component

Tags: angularjs

We have app A and app B and shared component C.

Both A and B includes C.

C is a form with fields and buttons. When pressing one of the buttons we popup a component called object-modal.

object-modal does not exist within C, A and B must implement this component.

When closing/saving the modal, common code located in shared components service should be called.

[image: Image trying to explain problem]

This feels too messy, is there a smarter way do design this ?

Here is a plunker:
https://plnkr.co/edit/Dm5ykOyB8XbLOOXTQ84U?p=preview

```
var C = angular.module('C', []);

C.component('common', {
  template:"<app-specific>{{$ctrl.text}}</app-specific>",
  controller:function($scope) {
    this.text = "Test";
  }
});
C.service("cService", function(){
  this.methodInC = function(){
    alert("back in C");
  }
})


var appA = angular.module('A', ["C"]);

appA.component('appSpecific', {
  template:"<input type='button' ng-click='$ctrl.click()' value='{{$ctrl.text}}'></input>",
  controller:function($scope, cService) {
    this.text = "Test A";
    this.click = function(){
      cService.methodInC();
    }
  }
}); 


var appB = angular.module('B', ["C"]);

appB.component('appSpecific', {
  template:"<button ng-click='$ctrl.click()'>{{$ctrl.text}}</button>",
  controller:function($scope, cService) {
    this.text = "Test B";
    this.click = function(){
      cService.methodInC();
    }
  }
}); 

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("appA"), ['A']);
  angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("appB"), ['B']);
});
```